# Can async execute a function twice at the same time?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Is it possible to print 'hello world' twice?

```
IS_RESTARTING = false;

on_error = function(err){
    if (IS_RESTARTING) return;
    IS_RESTARTING = true;
    console.log('hello world');
}
process.on('uncaughtException', on_error);
[...errors occurring in async processes...]
```

Comment: no because you have a shared variable between all the errors. `on_error = function(err){ console.log('hello world'); }` will do the job

Comment: @smnbbrv what if 2 errors happen at the same time, before the variable is true?

Comment: This is not possible. There is no 2 lines of code being ran at the same time... The only thing asynchronous programming does is execute other lines of code while we wait on another part of the script.

Comment: @AlexC. if you want this to be possible you must spawn a child process, so it might be executed in parallel. In your case even this is impossible because you are watching the same process